# Remove elements from list of lists - haskell

Tags: haskell

I need to remove elements stored in `[Char]` from list of lists `[[Char]]`. Lets have these elements - `"34"` and list of list like this - `["2345","16"]`. What I need to do is delete each one element from this list of lists. The elements will not occur multiple times in either of these. So I need result like this - `["25","16"]`. So far I have come up with this solution which is not working properly:

```
removeFromListOfLists list toRemove = map (\element -> removeFromList list element) toRemove

removeFromList list element = map (\listPart -> remove listPart element) list

remove listPart element = filter (\e -> e/=element) listPart
```

But what I get from this is: `[["245","16"],["235","16"]]`

Comment: What if the input was `["2435", "136"]`. Is the output then `["25", "16"]`?

Comment: I said that the elements will not occur multiple times so the the input will never be `["2435", "136"]`

Comment: that is not really the question. It is more do you want to remove the string (as a substring) or the individual characters?

Comment: individual characters, becuse `'3'` can occur in first list and `'4'` can occur in other one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
import Data.List

removeFromList items list = map handle list where
    handle y = filter (`notElem` items) y
```

Short version:

```
removeFromList items = map handle where
    handle = filter (`notElem` items)
```

Example call: `removeFromList "34" ["2345","16"]`

What you actaully do is, you map over the whole list, so you have got each list separatly.
As next step, you fold this specific list and check every item if it should be removed.

Comment: but what arguments should I pass to this function? I do not see the second argument which should be the list of lists ?

Comment: In Haskell you can omit arguments as they are passed at the end of the function. I will add it to my answer to avoid confusion

Comment: This actually works, thanks I just need a while to process it.

Comment: I have added a short and a long version for you, to see the difference

Comment: Your `handle` is very inefficient (O(m\*n^2), m the length of `items`, n the length of `y`) compared to the naive idiomatic solution ```handle = filter (`notElem` items)``` (O(m\*n)) or the efficient solution ```handle = filter (`S.notMember` S.fromList items)``` (O((m+n)\*log m)).

Comment: @DanielWagner Thanks, you are totally right. I just thought it is easier to understand. Nevertheless I added it to my answer

Answer (score 2):

The top-down way you organised your code is actually quite good; you can use it to guide your implementation. Let's begin with:

```
removeFromListOfLists :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
removeFromListOfLists toRemove lol = map (\list -> removeFromList toRemove list) lol
```

(I have flipped the order of the arguments with respect to your definition, as it usually more idiomatic to have the list you are processing as the last argument, for the sake of easier composition and partial application. Also note I'm mapping over the list of lists, which is arguably the more natural way of expressing this task.)

Now we drill down to `removeFromList`:

```
removeFromList :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

As you probably suspect, it can be expressed with `filter`:

```
removeFromList toRemove list = filter (\element -> shouldBeKept element) list
```

We still need to define the `shouldBeKept` test. It is slightly more convenient to do so through a local definition using `where`, rather than through a top-level definition:

```
removeFromList :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
removeFromList toRemove list = filter (\element -> shouldBeKept element) list
    where
    shouldBeKept element = element `notElem` toRemove
```

(This uses the [`notElem`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:notElem) function. Alternatively, though with unneeded verbosity, you might define a `shouldBeRemoved` test with [`elem`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:elem) and then use `not (shouldBeRemoved element)` when calling `filter`.)

For the sake of completeness, here is how I'd usually phrase these functions, in a more pointfree manner (judiciously "omit[ting] arguments", as [Stephan Strate put it in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49132203/remove-elements-from-list-of-lists-haskell/49133055#comment85269671_49132427)):

```
removeFromListOfLists :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
removeFromListOfLists toRemove = map (removeFromList toRemove)

removeFromList :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
removeFromList toRemove = filter shouldBeKept
    where
    shouldBeKept element = element `notElem` toRemove
```